# File not found while reading json file on Asset folder using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-assets

I am trying to write a new json data on my json file which is located in asset folder inside  mcdata folder.

```
fun writeToFile(fileName: String, fileContent: String) {
        try {
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(this.resources.assets.openFd("mcdata/$fileName").fileDescriptor)
            val outputWriter = OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream)
            outputWriter.write(fileContent)
            outputWriter.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            "Exception: ${e.message}".toLog()
        }
    }
```

I am getting `File not found Exception` on

```
FileOutputStream(this.resources.assets.openFd("mcdata/$fileName").fileDescriptor)
```

But when I use `this.resources.assets.open("mcdata/$fileName")` the it return the InputStream without any issue.

How I can write the new jsonObject on the file, which is located in  `mcdata/$fileName` under asset folder

Comment: You cannot change files in assets as they are read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't edit/modify data in asset folder in run time or after application installed. `assets folder are read only`.

So we move files into `Internal Storage` or to `cacheDir` to edit it.